# Near by places in React-native-Maps

Tags: google-maps, react-native, maps, react-native-maps

Is there a way to render nearby ATM's or restaurants using react native maps.

I'm trying to implement only in android.  I have  an array of latitudes and longitudes from which I have to calculate nearest one with current location.

if nothing possible via react-native-maps, using google navigate linking will be an alternate option.

share us a possible solution.

Comment: Are you able to find solution for this?? because I have to render restaurants , coffee shops near by User in React Native.

Comment: Just calculate distance between your current coordinates and values of restaurants,coofeshops etc(values from server) to near by constant(Lets Say 2KM).

Comment: means I have to pass latitude and longitude in the Google Place api then api Return restaurant, coffeeshops near by me based on the filter I have provide in the api call.then return data from the api will be displayed in the google map. is it ??

Comment: If your applications server is providing lats longs near by use them. otherwise follow your google place API approach

Comment: thanks for your feedback @Kartiikeya. :)